# vk_api: можно ли увеличить лимит wall.get() на количество обращений с помощью execute?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пытаюсь получить 100 самых свежих постов друзей и друзей-друзей. Количество таких пользователей измеряется десятками тысяч, соответственно ограничение метода wall.get() на 5000 запросов в сутки получается критичным (https://vk.com/dev/wall.get).

В vk api есть метод execute https://vk.com/dev/execute позволяющий за один запрос к серверу выполнить до 25 вызовов отдельных методов.

В сети встречал что за счет метода execute можно в 25 увеличить дневной лимиты вызовов wall.get()

соответственно попытался это реализовать используя питоновскую библиотеку vk_api. Вызов метода wall.get() c помощью execute осуществляется следующей функцией:

```
vk_get_all_items = vk_api.execute.VkFunction(
# "code" part is based on function vk_get_all_items from module vkTools
#https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/vk_api/tools.html#VkTools
# 0 in line: items = items + ri.slice(0); - defines offset for the results
args=('method', 'key', 'values', 'count', 'offset', "input_length"),
clean_args=('method', 'key', 'offset',"input_length"),
code='''
    var calls = 0,
        val_ind = 0,
        items = [],
        count = %(count)s,
        offset = %(offset)s,
        input_length = %(input_length)s,
        ri;
    while(calls < input_length) {
        var params = %(values)s[val_ind];
        calls = calls + 1;
        val_ind = val_ind + 1;

        params.offset = offset ;
        var response = API.%(method)s(params);
        ri = response.%(key)s;
        items = items + ri.slice(0);
        count = count + response.count;
    };
    return {
        count: count,
        items: items
     };
''')
```

Функцию вызываю из **main**() следующей строчкой:

```
        response = vk_get_all_items(vk_session,
        method = 'wall.get', key = 'items', values = friends_dic[25*ind: 25*ind + 25], count = 0, offset = 0, input_length = 25)
```

где values это листы по 25 элементов, следующего вида:

```
[{'owner_id': 12345, 'count' : 100},{'owner_id': 67890, 'count': 100}, ... ]
```

Все работает, но несмотря на использование execute обрабатывает только 5000 аккаунтов из списка.

Есть ли здесь какая-то принципиальная ошибка или на самом деле execute не увеличивает лимит конкретного метода и каждый запрос внутри запроса execute считается отдельно?

Comment: Было бы странно, если бы они не считались отдельно

Comment: Те действительно с помощью execute нельзя увеличить количество запросов в сутки, а только количество информации получаемый за одно обращение к серверу? Получается, что сделать поиск по постам друзей и друзей-друзей (чего по умолчанию в вк, по непонятным мне причинам, нет, хотя очень полезно) в принципе невозможно?

Comment: Как это нет https://vk.com/dev.php?method=wall.search

Comment: Ну на этот метод еще более жесткие ограничения - 1000. Если нужно провести несколько поисков подряд по разным ключевым словам, то 1000 запросов вообще ни о чем. Собственно поэтому я использовал метод wall.get получал все посты, и дальше искал по ним необходимую информацию не завися от ограничений api

Comment: ЗЫ задачка у меня вполне практическая - по ключевому слову получить все посты друзей и друзей-друзей новее определенного периода.

Comment: Ограничения в api добавлены специально для того, чтобы вы так не делали :)

Answer (score 0):

Да, вы верно думаете, **execute не увеличивает [дневной лимит запросов](https://vk.com/dev/data_limits)**. И, как верно отметили в комментариях, *ограничения в api добавлены специально для того, чтобы вы так не делали*.

Решение, на удивление, есть. Можно использовать несколько токенов, так как лимиты распространяются по ним. То есть, теоретически, можно подготовить *X* токенов, сделать *5000* запросов `wall.get` на первом токене, взять новый токен и повторять. Тогда вы сможете сделать *5000*X* запросов. Думаю, этого будет достаточно для решения вашей задачи.

---

В любом случае, лимиты создаются не просто так. За злоупотребление ВКонтакте всегда может отключить API (4.6 [dev.vk.com/rules](https://dev.vk.com/rules)). Возможно, лучше просто пересмотреть логику приложения или придумать альтернативное решение.